# Determine if the time is after Midnight and roll back date if it is - batch script

Tags: datetime, batch-file

I wrote a batch script to automate some pretty repetitive stuff for my restaurants end of night reports (and would like to push it company wide) and it works great in most circumstances. However some nights the reports get run after midnight and the date ends up being wrong. I thought about using an IF ELSE statement to check the time and adjust the date variable but you run into issues on the last/first day of the month(ie do I roll back to a 28, 30, or 31).

Is there a function that can do this or do I need to write an IF statement for each set of months ending in 28, 30, and 31? Using batch script is preferred as I don't know what software beyond Windows is installed on each system and I don't currently have the ability to add any.

Below is the simplified version of the code I'm currently using:

```shell
@For /F "Tokens=1-5Delims=/: " %%G In (
    '""%__AppDir__%Robocopy.exe" \: . /NJH /L|"%__AppDir__%find.exe" " 123""'
)Do @Set "bdate=%%G-%%H-%%I"
 
mkdir "X:\EON Files\%bdate%"

move /Y "X:\EON Files\example" "X:\EON Files\%bdate%\%bdate%-example"

exit
```

Comment: I've never used `robocopy` so I'd ask whether it produces `2022/01/22 13:26:45 ERROR 123 ...` universally - and is there a caret missing before the pipe, or does the plethora of quotes obviate it? I'd assign `%%G`..`%%K` to `byear`..`bminute`, preceding each 2-digit string with `1` (So `set bmonth=1%%H` to set January to `101` because batch assumes that a leading `0` means the string is **octal** and August would be `08` which is invalid octal, but `108` is valid decimal.  You can then re-assemble `bdate` from `%byear%-%bmonth:~-2%-%bday:~-2%` where the `-2` means "last 2 characters of"

Comment: So, if `bhour` is less than `103` then it's before 3am. so do the adjustment. Simply `set /a bday-=1` to find the prior day, if `bday` is then `100`, decrement `bmonth` by following the bouncing ball and set `bday` to `131`. Then `for %%m in (104 106 109 111) do set bday=130`. If `bmonth` is `100`, set it to `112` and decrement `byear`. Finally, if `bmonth` is `102`, set `bday` to `128` and if `byear %% 4` (byear mod 4) is zero, then increment `bday` (or set it to `129`) and job done